# Need to hide player

Tags: php

I'm trying to hide a youtube player when there is no yt id in the row/colum, I'm trying but don't know what i'm doing wrong. thank you very much

```
include 'config.php';
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $naamID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
    $id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $idnext = $id + 1;
    $gn     = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE nameID='".$nameID."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $go     = (" SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='".$id."' and youtube='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $gnn    = mysql_query($gn) or die(mysql_error());
    $goo    = mysql_query($go) or die(mysql_error());
    $gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn);
    $gooo   = mysql_fetch_array($goo);


        // down here is the problem
        if(!empty($gooo)){
        echo 'no video player';
        } else {

        echo '<h1> '.$gooo["title"].'</h1><br />';
        echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$gooo["youtube"].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />';

        }
```

Comment: What does `$gooo` contain at run time? (You should choose better variable names!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function empty returns true if the variable is empty so remove !.

```
if(empty($gooo)){
        echo 'no video player';
        } else {

        echo '<h1> '.$gooo["title"].'</h1><br />';
        echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$gooo["youtube"].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />';

        }
```

Comment: ok whats inside the variable   $gooo because i am certain it is empty so you need to put something else there to check if the ideo exists.

Comment: thank you just replaced `if(empty($gooo['youtube'])){`